# Have browser return to the same place on page on redirect_to :back (using rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Does this require javascript? I notice on a lot of pages, particularly wikipedia, that if I scroll halfway down a page to some arbitrary point, click a link, and the click 'Back', I return to the same arbitrary point on the previous page I was on. Is this using javascript or a natural property of the web browser?

When I click a service link in my app, such as a background process that needs to run, I use redirect_to :back or request.referrer (using the latter) but the page is at the top. Is wikipedia using javascript or are they using some special caching? The only difference between mine is that I actually change a small graphic on the page when they click the link, so I guess the page would need to 'reload' in order to show this, but was hoping it could be at the same spot. TO BE CLEAR: I am trying to avoid using javascript or keeping track of where they were on the page manually.

Comment: Take a look at your url. Does it end with a # and then some text? If so, it’s using what’s referred to as a url anchor, which scrolls to the corresponding html id on the page. No JavaScript required.

Comment: No, wikipedia is not using anchors in this case, as if I clicked on a TOC link. I am selecting a regular page, and then manually scrolling down the page, then clicking on another link, then clicking 'Back'.

Comment: Your browser will remember your scroll position of your last page if you’re using your browser’s built in back button. If your main content gets ajaxed in, it’s possible that it won’t scroll to the correct place because of the page briefly being very short before content is added.

Comment: No ajax, no javascript in page. Just html. I think the real problem is that some of the content is being changed on the page, albeit one tiny little image, so I guess it needs to reload and won't know where to go. I can't replicate this with wikipedia since the pages are like the same as when I was on them before.

Comment: BTW: if I can confirm this is normal behavior I can move on.